# WhatsApp Web and Phone connection

Tags: whatsapp

I have a problem when using WhatsApp web - my WhatsApp web connects fine but my phone fails to keep updated while I use WhatsApp web. Only way I can solve it is by closing WhatsApp web and then restarting my phone. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic on this site. It might be on topic in [android.se] or [apple.se].